# Fitting decays in R

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, simulation

I have a data like that I want to fit decay.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
t = 1:100
x=1:80
y1=sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
y1<-y1 %>% jitter()
y2 = 24 + (60 - 24) * -0.01 * x %>% jitter(10)



df1 <- tibble(t = t, y = y1, sensor = 'sensor1') %>% 
  rbind(. , data.frame(t = x, y = y2, sensor = 'sensor2'))


fit <- nls(y ~ SSasymp(t, yf, y0, log_alpha), data = sensor1)
fit

# Fit the data
fitted <- df %>% 
  nest(-sensor) %>%
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~nls(y ~ SSasymp(t, yf, y0, log_alpha), data = .)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy),
    augmented = map(fit, augment),
  )
```

And I got :

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `fit = map(data, ~nls(y ~ SSasymp(t, yf, y0, log_alpha), data = .))`.
Caused by error in `nls()`:
! singular gradient

Could you please let me where was the issue.

Comment: The sample data don't look like they can easily be fitted to this model

Comment: The code was designed for fitting exponential decays.

Comment: Yes, but if you plot the data, sensor1 looks like random, non-decaying noise, and sensor2 looks like a linear decline without an asymptote. The error is telling you that the parameters cannot be optimised based on the supplied data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I want to fit it if  both sensor1 and  sensor will be random, non-decaying noise. how should be? That  helps me too.

Comment: The point is that there _isn't_ an optimal fit - at least one of the parameters has multiple (even infinite) values that give the same result. It doesn't make any sense to fit it. You would need to look at different models.